# plotting groupby inside for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble with plotting a groupby inside of a for loop. I am trying to generate a groupby barplot for each categorical feature in my data, but when I run the loop, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(include = ['object']):
    plt.figure(figsize = (12, 7))
    df.groupby(col).col2.mean().plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.show();
```

Anybody know why this is not generating any plots?

Comment: Please give example of input df, what the output you got and what the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of desired columns you need to groupby then loop over those, example:

let's assume you always want to group col3 by mean over each other column in the dataframe, so you first return a list of all other dataframe apart from col3, then you loop over the list:

```
neededCols = [c for c in df if c is not 'col3']

for col in neededCols:
    plt.figure(figsize = (12, 7))
    df.groupby(col).col3.mean().plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey Mit, thanks for replying, however this is still not working, the notebook just keeps running and not producing anything, like it is stuck

Comment: What do you mena stuck? does it crash reporting any errors? or just runs but not finishes?

Comment: just runs but doesn't finish, isn't producing any output

Comment: how many columns do you have in your df? and did you append anything in the above code?

Comment: I have 70 columns in the df, with about 40 of those being categorical (the ones I want to plot), and I am not appending anything

Comment: Update: It just finished running and looks like it is trying to plot everything on one plot

Comment: Ok so the bit long run time suggest your data is big therefore takes a while to group. however it shouldn't plot everything on one plot, it should be plotting each separately as it goes, can you add a sample of your dataframe and capture the code you're using?

Comment: Hey Mit, it just finished, your solution worked, thanks a lot, for some reason it looks like placing those columns into a list with a list comprehension (as you suggested) worked, where when I was looping over the columns when they weren't in a list it wasn't working, cheers

Comment: Glad to hear that, all the best!